# JavaScript alertbox if Django form missing fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I would like to implement some JQuery elements in my Django website application to render it dynamical.

For exemple, users are filling a form and an alertbox appears depending if my Django form is well filled or not.

- If Django form is well filled it'll give : "Form has been created"
- If Django form is not correctly filled it'll give : "Please, look your form"

I tried some things and my html file looks like this :

```
    <form class = "form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
        <br></br>
        {{ form.as_p}} <!-- Display child part formulary -->
        <br></br>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Valider le formulaire</button>
    </form>

        {% if form.is_valid %}
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Le formulaire a été créé");
        }
        </script>
        {% else %}
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Le formulaire n'a pas été créé car champ(s) invalide(s)");
        }
        </script>
        {% endif %}
```

My view looks like :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form_unique_number(request) :

    validity = []
    #User fill some fields
    query_social_number = request.GET.get('social_number')
    query_social_number_father = request.GET.get('social_number_father')
    query_social_number_mother = request.GET.get('social_number_mother')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = BirthCertificateForm2(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated2', kwargs={'id': post.id}))
     ...
```

How I could write this AlertBox in my files ?

Thank you !

PS : I am very new with JQuery. First time I'm using it

**EDIT :**

I tried something like this, but none alert appears :

```
<form class = "form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
                <br></br>
                {{ form.as_p}} <!-- Display child part formulary -->
                <br></br>

                <button type="input">Valider</button>
            </form>


            <script type="text/javascript" >
                $(document).on('Valider', 'form.form', function(form) {
                var $form = $(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/path_to_directory/BC_form2.html",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(form) {
                    alert("L'acte de naissance a été créé");
                    }
                });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to submit your data to view then validate the data and return the json of your response. After that you can show the alert based on your return. You can use `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()` and other function based on what you need. Just make sure you can handle the data in ajax based on your response from view.

**UPDATED**

For you edit case you have to know more about the jQuery. Instead of

`$(document).on('Valider', 'form.form', function(form)`

you should

`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function(form)`

For `event` is kind of input or something happen that you would like to handle, for example when you want to handle click then you use `click` or something change you can use `change`.

For `selector` are some kind of id, class or other type that you got from you html element. So in your case if you want to use `click` event the code would be like

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-validate', function(e){
    var form = $(".form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_on_your_view and already registered in you url.py",
        type: "POST",
        success:function(response){
            alert("L'acte de naissance a été créé");
        }
    });
}
```

for your button you have to update to

```
<button type="input" class="btn-validate">Valider</button>
```

Comment: Ok It seems to be what I've done. I will see more documentations about ajax and possibilities with my project.